# Add a linking model between two models with existing associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have two models:

```
class User
  belongs_to :branch
end

class Branch
  has_many :users
end
```

I would like to add an extra association between these two models with an extra attribute, so I think I need another linking model?

```
class BranchContact
  enum contact_type: {
    type_one: 0,
    type_two: 1
  }
end
```

but I'm having problems wrapping my head around 1) if a link table and new model is the right approach and 2) what associations should go in each model such that `Branch.branch_contacts` returns a list of BranchContacts i.e Users with contact_type

Thanks for any help

```
class User
  belongs_to :branch
  belongs_to :branch_contact
end

class Branch
  has_many :users
  has_many :branch_contacts, through: :users
end

class BranchContact
  belongs_to :branch
  belongs_to :user

  enum contact_type: {
    type_one: 0,
    type_two: 1
  }
end
```

I got:

```
> obj = Branch.last.branch_contacts.build(branch: Branch.last, user_id: Branch.last.users.last.id, contact_type: :finance)
> obj.save!
true
> Branch.last.branch_contacts
[]
```

I was expecting the branch contact I just saved to be related to the Branch

Comment: If it is only one attribute, would be tempted to just add it to the user and call it a day, since they can only belong to a single branch. Otherwise, your Branch relations are backwards, it should have many users through branch_contacts.

Comment: yeah I think you're probably right @dbugger